# count value occurance and group by date

Tags: php, sql

I get this date from datebase

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [page] => login
        [timestamp] => 2013-11-06 12:06:30
    )

[1] => Array
        [page] => changepage
        [timestamp] => 2013-11-06 12:06:31
    )
```

and so on..

I want to count the entries from the same day to make

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
  [timestamp] => 2013-11-06 // only by the same day..
  [count] =>  4
  )
)
```

or even

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => Array
   (
    [timestamp] => 2013-11-06
    [login] => 2
    [changepage] => 4
   )
 )
```

I've tried

```
   function format($data)
{
    $dates = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    {

    if ($data[$i]['page'] == 'login')
        {
            if (!isset($dates[explode(' ', $data[$i]['timestamp'])[0]]))
                array_push($dates, array('date' => explode(' ', $data[$i]['timestamp'])[0], 'login' => 1));
            else
            {
                foreach ($dates as $date) {
                    if ($date['date'] == explode(' ', $data[$i]['timestamp'])[0])
                        $date['login'] += 1;
                         }
            }
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

but that gives me only one record of

```
    Array( Array ( 'timestamp' => '2013-11-06', 'login' => 1) )
```

In conclosion I want to sum the entries with the same day and same page 
(My best solution would be getting 2 arrays one with sum of all the pages and one with detailed page sum)

Comment: Show us what you have tried already

Comment: updated with my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to your question:

```
function format($data) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($data as $item) {
    $date = substr($item['timestamp'], 0, 10);
    @$result[$date]['timestamp'] = $date;
    @$result[$date][$item['page']]++;
  }
  sort($result);
  return $result;
}
```

For each item in the array, it first truncates the time part of the `timestamp` field using `substr`. Use the date value as the key of the result array, add a `timestamp` field using this same date value, and increase the value of the other fields (containing page names). I use @ operator here to prevent the Notice error when the key (index) doesn't exist yet.

After all items have been processed, sort the result array to change the keys into numeric indices and it becomes a regular array.

Here's the test I run:

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'page' => 'login',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-06 12:06:30'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'changepage',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-06 12:06:45'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'login',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-06 13:06:30'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'changepage',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-06 14:06:45'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'changepage',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-06 14:06:50'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'login',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-07 12:06:30'
  ),
  array(
    'page' => 'changepage',
    'timestamp' => '2013-11-07 12:06:45'
  )
);

print_r(format($data));
```

Anda the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2013-11-06
            [login] => 2
            [changepage] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2013-11-07
            [login] => 1
            [changepage] => 1
        )

)
```

There, hope it helps!